# iPython warning in Emacs: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR)

Tags: emacs, ipython

How do I get ipython working correctly under emacs?

Following the [ipython docs recommendation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html), I have enabled ipython:

```lisp
(require 'python)
(setq python-shell-interpreter "ipython")
```

I get the following warning when I start the ipython server.

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Jul  9 2019, 18:15:00) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
```

The "`[In]`" prompts do not print at all.  And also when code is sent from another buffer (e.g. through `python-shell-send-buffer`).  Here is a sample screen dump (I'm guessing that the `i 8 i 8` is from the prompt not being properly displayed):

```
WARNING: your terminal doesn't support cursor position requests (CPR).
i
8
i
8

hello world
```

Interactively, the "`[Out]`" prompts sometimes display and sometimes not:

```
print('hello world')

hello world

4

Out[3]: 4
```

Emacs I'm running on macos:

```
This is GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0, NS appkit-1348.17 Version 10.10.5 (Build 14F2511))
 of 2019-09-02
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(setq python-shell-interpreter-args "--simple-prompt -i")
```

ipython assumes you have a "normal" terminal, but in Emacs it runs under a ["dumb" terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal#Dumb_terminals).  Really, ipython should be able to know this through the `TERM` environment variable.  Looks like there was some recent effort on this: https://github.com/prompt-toolkit/python-prompt-toolkit/issues/390.  Hopefully it will Just Work in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

I downgrade my ipython or ipdb version and the problem solved...
I dont know why.

I met this problem in my virtual env, and the ipython version is 7.16.1
But when I deactivate the virtual env, the problem didn't happen and this time the version of ipython is 7.7.0.
So I degrade the version in my virtual env.

Comment: More specifically, the warning still occurs, but the input and output in the interactive ipython is normal.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue while running my python script inside a Docker container. I had forgotten to include the `-i` flag on `docker run`. After adding the flag, this warning cleared and ipdb behaved as expected.